# R table from rows

Tags: r

I have some data frames which hold the results of a survey. The first frame lists the question ids (q_id) for each question in the survey:

```
  q_id
1   q1
2   q2
3   q3
```

The second data frame holds responses (res) for each subject (s_id) for every question that subject responded to. A subject can skip questions:

```
  s_id q_id res
1    1   q1   a
2    2   q1   b
3    1   q2   b
```

What I want to generate is a table which shows the responses to each question, where the columns are the question ids and each row represents a subject. In the above examples, the table would look like this:

```
  q1 q2  q3
1  a  b  NA
2  b  NA NA
```

What is the best way to generate such a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your question data.frame is `DQ` and your answers `DT`

You need to make sure that your `q_id` column in your answers has all the levels available

```
DT$q_id <- factor(as.character(DT$q_id), levels = levels(DQ$q_id))
```

then you can use `reshape2` and `dcast` with `drop = FALSE` to cast as you wish

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(DT, s_id~q_id, value.var = 'res', drop = FALSE)
  s_id q1   q2   q3
1    1  a    b <NA>
2    2  b <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> dat <- read.table(text="  s_id q_id res
+ 1    1   q1   a
+ 2    2   q1   b
+ 3    1   q2   b", header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Create a dummy entry for each question:

> dat<- rbind(dat, data.frame(s_id=1,q_id=qdat$q_id, res= NA))
> dat
  s_id q_id  res
1    1   q1    a
2    2   q1    b
3    1   q2    b
4    1   q1 <NA>
5    1   q2 <NA>
6    1   q3 <NA>
> reshape(dat,  timevar="q_id", idvar="s_id", direction ="wide")
  s_id res.q1 res.q2 res.q3
1    1      a      b   <NA>
2    2      b   <NA>   <NA>
```